# JComboBox width issue in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, gridbaglayout

When I put a JComboBox into a JPanel with GridBagLayout, I find the longest JComboBox item will not fully show, instead, it show part of with '...'

For example, it show 'Healthcare Ingred...' for 'Healthcare Ingredient'.

Please have a look at the screenshot here:

[image: JComboBox width issue]

Code is something like this:

```
JPanel infoPanel = JPanel(new GridBagLayout());            
dataTypeCB = new JComboBox(dataTypeList.toArray());
infoPanel.add(dataTypeCB, new GridBagConstraints(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(5,5,5,5), 0, 0));
```

I find out two solution already:

1. overwrite the getPreferenceSize of JComboBox, however a bit annoying.
2. wrap the JComboBox with a JPanel, like below, however the warpped JPanel introduce some intents and cause alignment issue instead, still not perfect:

code of second solution:

```
dataTypeCB = new JComboBox(dataTypeList.toArray());
JPanel dataTypeCBPanel = new JPanel();//make item can be fully show up.
dataTypeCBPanel.add(dataTypeCB, BorderLayout.CENTER);
infoPanel.add(dataTypeCBPanel, new GridBagConstraints(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(5,5,5,5), 0, 0));
```

My question is : is any other easy way to solve this issue?

Enviroment: windows 7 with JDK 1.6_25(64bit version)

Many Thanks

Comment: hmm ... the size requirement is calculated internally to that of the widest item, which seems to be working as expected in your screenshot. Could it be that the renderer of the selectedItem (that is the combo itself) is using a slightly bigger font than the dropdown list? BTW, best to provide a SSCCE to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve this issue by myself.

The reason why I get this, is because I am using a library with the name "JIDE", which bring its LookAndFeel into my application.

I tested on the JDK's default look and feel, they looks do not have this issue. 
Then I switch to JIDE's look and Feel, then I can reproduce this issue.

So I think the problem is related with the LookAndFeel. The ComboBoxUI class.

So what I really need to do is to write my own ComboBoxUI or extends the UI class in JIDE library.

Sorry for did not give enough information for this, when I ask question, I did not realize it is related with the LookAndFeel.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

have look at [JComboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setPrototypeDisplayValue%28E%29)

Comment: thanks for answer, does this mean i need to go through all items, find the longest one, then setPrototypeDisplayValue? Many Thanks

Comment: `find the longest one` should be best of options or to set the strict size `("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")` to display majority of..., and let's to resize for [JComboBoxes JPopup](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/11/28/combo-box-popup/)

Comment: +1, I just learned recently from you, how wonderful this method is :-)

Comment: @mKorbel Thanks for comments. I am using a renderer to get the display name, the items in JComboBox are actually just ids. Yes, I can get the display name first, and get the longest one, and get the size, but seems still painful